# Как у функции javascript может быть свой метод, как у объекта?

Tags: javascript

Я недавно наткнулся на данный код и не могу понять, как это работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
var Fn = function () {
// …
}
Fn.set = function () {
// …
}
```

Comment: Вам стоит почитать какую нибудь литературу по JS. Этот язык очень сильно отличается от других языков и его код смотреть очень не привычно. Если коротко, то в JS очень далеко пошли в предложении "все есть объект". Функция такой же объект, как и все остальное в языке и у нее могут быть свои свойства и методы. А еще функция может быть не только объектом, но и классом (с точки зрения других ООП языков)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: learn.javascript.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JavaScript ES6 синтаксис `class Hello {}` является синтаксическим сахаром для старой записи (`function Hello () {}`). В объектно-ориентированном программировании классы могут иметь статические методы. И если записывать классы не в стиле ES6, то это и будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
var MyClass = function () {
    // constructor
}

MyClass.sayHello = function () {
    alert ("Hello!")
}
```

Альтернатива на ES6:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        // constructor
    }

    static sayHello () {
        alert ("Hello!")
    }
}
```

Помог комментарий [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939996/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-javascript-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0/1077279#comment1562425_939996).